# Criar array com dados de retorno do Firebase

Tags: array, angular, typescript, ionic3, firestore

Precisaria criar um novo array a partir do retorno da URL de imagens do Firebase

O array 'newImgList' não recebe nada.

tarefa.ts

```
 imgList: [];
 newImgList: any = [];

 constructor(...) {

    this.tarefaId = this.navParams.get('tarefaId');
    this.imgList = this.navParams.get('imgList');
    this.listImage(this.tarefaId);    
    this.getTarefa();
  }



  listImage (tarefaId: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.imgList.length; i++) {
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let imageRef = storageRef.child(`tarefas/${tarefaId}/${this.imgList[i]}`);
      imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {    
        this.newImgList.push(url);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        alert("erro");
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Qual o erro que vc esta recebendo?

Comment: não esta populando o array "newImgList". se dou um console.log nele ta vazio.

Comment: ele so vai estar populado dentro do then pq é assincrono

Comment: @EduardoVargas, sou meio cru nisso. poderia exemplificar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc só vai conseguir ver o conteúdo no console quando a lista acabar de receber os dados assíncronos do servidor. Use ASYNC/AWAIT.
Dê uma estudada sobre ASYNC/AWAIT, é bem importante pra quem trabalha com requisições de servidores.

ps: Não testei o código.

```
 imgList: [];
 newImgList: any = [];

 constructor(...) {

    this.tarefaId = this.navParams.get('tarefaId');
    this.imgList = this.navParams.get('imgList');
    this.listImage(this.tarefaId);    
    this.getTarefa();
  }



  async listImage (tarefaId: string) {
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.imgList.length; i++) {
      let imageRef = storageRef.child(`tarefas/${tarefaId}/${this.imgList[i]}`);
      await imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {    
        this.newImgList.push(url);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        alert("erro");
      });
    }

    console.log(this.newImgList);
  }
```

Comment: Ahh. "let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();", use fora do laço, vc não precisa pegar várias vezes a mesma referência.